# Docker portainer tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connect: connection refused

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use `portainer/portainer:1.24.1-alpine`.
My docker in my windows, my container is linux.

```
portainer | 2020/09/04 12:42:57 Get http://localhost:2375/_ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connect: connection refused
```

My `docker-compose.yml`, i tried it on linux as host and `#command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock` works fine, but now I am using do windows as HOST.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer:1.24.1-alpine
    #command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock << i am not using linux as HOST.
    command: -H tcp://localhost:2375 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9999:9000
    volumes:
    # - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - web_data:/data

volumes:
  web_data:
    driver: local
```

---

What should I used on line `command: -H ???????`?

Comment: possibly some helpful info here: https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-containers-how-to-access-in-windows-host-machine-port-from-container/23250/5

Comment: Thanks for the link, but his container are `Windows Containers`. My container still be `Linux Container`. Only my host is windows.

Comment: ah, of course. I wonder if `host.docker.internal` will work for you? If the docker daemon is available on localhost on windows at localhost:2375, then maybe you can access it within the container on `host.docker.internal:2375`?

Comment: @maxm, I will test it.

Comment: @maxn, That was the solution. Use the `host.docker.internal`. Solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it

Comment: If you want to make the answer, I will be glad to mark it as correct. haha :D